# Android: creating a Custom view as Marker in Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker

Strangely enough, I haven't seen a proper answer anywhere else on here. It might not be possible, but I'm still taking a shot.

In the latest Google Maps API version for Android, I want to create a custom View that would be placed over the marker like so once you click on it :

[Map Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVi6B.png)

[image]

Of course, I want to be able to interact with its intern components, i.e. the listview.
The menu would still show up and remain attached to the marker even if you move around on the map.
From what I've seen you can only render a Bitmap on the map. Is there really no workaround ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use [Info window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows) to display custom layout on google maps.

This is the sample code from the [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows).

```
public class MarkerDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnInfoWindowClickListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;
        // Add markers to the map and do other map setup.
        ...
        // Set a listener for info window events.
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Info window clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

> However, Info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an
>   image onto the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are
>   disregarded and you cannot distinguish between click events on various
>   parts of the view. You are advised not to place interactive components
>   — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom
>   info window.

Comment: It's a nice UI component, but I unfortunately need to be able to interact with the listview. Thank anyway